# How to detect cgPath in cgRect

Tags: swift, xcode, uibezierpath, cgrect, cgpath

I can detect only start point(touchBegan) that contain in c1 and end point(touchEnded) that contain in c2 but I can't detect path between them in c3, How should I do ?

[Application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgmWS.png)

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
    self.contentMode = .scaleToFill
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    swiped = false
    lastPoint = touch?.location(in: self)
    firstPoint = lastPoint
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    swiped = true
    let currentPoint = touch?.location(in: self) 
    lastPoint = currentPoint
    linePoint = lastPoint
    drawShapeLayer(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint!)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        drawShapeLayer(from: lastPoint, to: lastPoint!)
    }

    if  c1.contains(firstPoint) && c3.contains(linePoint) && c2.contains(lastPoint){
        AlertView.instance.showAlert(title: "Hooray!", message: "You made it!", alertType : .success)
    }

    else {
         AlertView.instance.showAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "You've almost got it.", alertType : .failure)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: iirc when you override even one of the touch events methods without calling `super` then you are meant to override them all, even if the override does nothing. `touchesCancelled(_:with:)` isn't overridden here.

Comment: Also I think you have a logic error in `touchesMoved`.  You are assigning lastPoint = currentPoint, and then linePoint = lastPoint, so all three variables have the same value (currentPoint).  The you try to draw from lastPoint to currentPoint, but these are now the same point so won't draw a line.  It will also have a knock-on effect on touchesEnded when you test all these points.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments above, I think the there is a logic error in `touchesMoved` and you need to reorder the code if you are trying to draw a three point line, and then later check that each point is in a specific view area.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
      swiped = true
      currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
      drawShapeLayer(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint)
      lastPoint = currentPoint
      linePoint = currentPoint
   }
}
```

(Also safely unwrapped touch to remove the optional and avoid crashes in the v unlikely scenario where touches.first is nil)